# Rellenar datos faltantes de una columna con una lista

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un dataset con el precio de un inmueble en dolares y en moneda local. Para ciertos valores, mi precio en dolares es Nan.

Luego de hacer los calculos, obtuve el valor con el cual tengo que reemplazar cada Nan en un formato de lista

El problema radica a la hora de reemplazar cada Nan con el valor indicado en la lista. Probe con `fillna` pensando que saldría facilmente pero no me ha dado resultado.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Creación del dataframe
lista = [[np.nan, 3236],[np.nan, 1976],[np.nan, 1612],[np.nan, 2509]]
df = pd.DataFrame(lista, columns =["price_usd", "price_local_currency"])

# Lista con los valores a rellenar
valores = pd.Series(data = [183, 112, 91, 142], index = [120,137,157,166])

# Resultado esperado:
lista_esperada = [[183, 3236],[112, 1976],[91, 1612],[142, 2509]]
df_esperado = pd.DataFrame(lista_esperada, columns =["price_usd", 
"price_local_currency"])
```

Aclaraciónes:

- El índice del dataframe es el mismo que el índice de la lista valores solo que, no supe como modificarle el índice al dataframe para dar el ejemplo
- El dataframe original (`df`) no es del mismo tamaño que la lista `valores`.

Comment: Buenas, su pregunta no me queda del todo clara ¿Cuales son los valores que desea reemplazar en el `df`? Por favor modifique su respuesta mostrando la salida que espera recibir

Comment: @Jred0n29 Ya lo agregue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

La forma más fácil de hacerlo es primero obtener las celdas que deseas "reemplazar" utilizando [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).

Utilizando tus datos y agregando algunas filas para mostrar que solo reemplaza los `NaN` de forma correcta creamos un `dataframe`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Creación del dataframe
lista = [[np.nan, 3236],[np.nan, 1976], [9,9999], [np.nan, 1612],[np.nan, 2509], [10, 2456]]
df = pd.DataFrame(lista, columns =["price_usd", "price_local_currency"])
```

Esto crea el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
    price_usd   price_local_currency
0   NaN         3236
1   NaN         1976
2   9.0         9999
3   NaN         1612
4   NaN         2509
5   10.0        2456
```

Obtenemos las "celdas" de la columna `price_usd` que son `NaN`

```
df['price_usd'].isna()
```

Esto devuelve una serie de booleanos

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
Name: price_usd, dtype: bool
```

Que utilizaremos junto con `loc()` para obtener las celdas que son `NaN`

```
df.loc[df['price_usd'].isna(), 'price_usd']
```

Ahora, creamos la serie con los valores e índices que deseamos "copiar" en el `dataframe` original

```
valores = pd.Series([183, 112, 91, 142], index = [0,1,3,4], name = 'price_usd')
```

Esto genera la siguiente serie (**Nota:** En tu pregunta los índices no coinciden con el ejemplo, pero espero que en tu código si coincidan, de otra forma no va a funcionar correctamente):

```
0    183
1    112
3     91
4    142
Name: price_usd, dtype: int64
```

Utilizamos esta serie para rellenar los `NaN` de nuestra selección anterior (Utilizanod `loc()`)

```
df.loc[df['price_usd'].isna(), 'price_usd'] = valores
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Creación del dataframe
lista = [[np.nan, 3236],[np.nan, 1976], [9,9999], [np.nan, 1612],[np.nan, 2509], [10, 2456]]
df = pd.DataFrame(lista, columns =["price_usd", "price_local_currency"])

valores = pd.Series([183, 112, 91, 142], index = [0,1,3,4], name = 'price_usd')

df.loc[df['price_usd'].isna(), 'price_usd'] = valores
```

Al imprimir `df` obtenemos el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
    price_usd   price_local_currency
0   183.0       3236
1   112.0       1976
2   9.0         9999
3   91.0        1612
4   142.0       2509
5   10.0        2456
```

Comment: Gracias! Me funcionó a la perfección.

Answer (score 0):

Según lo comprendido lo que se desea es reemplazar en la columna *"price_usd"* los datos de la serie `valores` suponiendo que la longitud de la serie será igual a la longitud del `df`. Una manera sencilla y no tan compleja sería asignar a dicha columna la *[serie](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html)* `valores` de la siguiente manera:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Creación del dataframe
lista = [[np.nan, 3236],[np.nan, 1976],[np.nan, 1612],[np.nan, 2509]]
df = pd.DataFrame(lista, columns =["price_usd", "price_local_currency"])

valores = pd.Series(data = [183, 112, 91, 142]) #omito los indices ya que no hace falta
df["price_usd"] = valores #Asignamos a la columna la serie 
print(df)
```

### Como resultado obtendremos:

```
  price_usd  price_local_currency
0        183                  3236
1        112                  1976
2         91                  1612
3        142                  2509
```

Como puede notar se reemplazan los datos de la serie en la columna *"price_usd"*

Comment: Creo que esto no resuelve el problema del OP, en la columna hay celdas que ya tienen valores (Según entiendo) y por eso la serie la utilizo para crear un `dataframe` que quiere utilizar para rellenar las celdas NaN

Comment: Has comprendido bien pero, el problema es que el dataframe original no es del mismo tamaño que la serie `valores`. Ahora lo aclaro en la pregunta

Comment: En tal caso ¿Se ira repitiendo el valor de la lista?

Answer (score -2):

tal parece que solo quieres reemplazar los valores de la columna "price_usd", por los de la serie "valores". Si de por sí ya sabes que el el largo de la columna es igual al largo de los valores que quieres reemplazar, entonces:

```
 #Aquí está el problema, no te compliques si el index da lo mismo, solo defínelo como lista :)      
 valores = [183, 112, 91, 143]

 df["prices_usd"] = valores
```

Comment: Esta respuesta parece ser lo mismo que ya había publicado Jred0n29 ¿Cuál sería la diferencia?